# Alfresco Thumbnail creation not works

Tags: alfresco

I do not see Thumbnail for the image type ( png ) in the Document Library.

I see properly the Thumbnail of PDF and DOC

Other error when i try to change Alfresco Icon:

Unsupported transformation: transformer.ImageMagick image/png to image/png

imagemagick version: 7.0.5-2

Configuration in global properties:

```
### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=E:/alfresco-community/libreoffice/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=9100
img.root=E:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.dyn=${img.root}\\lib
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
alfresco-pdf-renderer.root=E:\\alfresco-community\\alfresco-pdf-renderer
alfresco-pdf-renderer.exe=${alfresco-pdf-renderer.root}\\alfresco-pdf-renderer.exe
```

Please, help

Comment: Where did you install Image Magick into? What is the exact path to the `convert.exe` program?

Comment: Does your Imagemagick include the delegate for PNG. Does `convert -version` list png for a delegate? What do you get returned for this command.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

i SOLVED the issue.



I think that the Imagemagick inside the Alfresco-community release has a bug.
Imagemagick version: 7.0.5-2
I installed last version with all flags during installation wizard ( NOT for associate files to ImageMagick )
Config in global properties:
img.root=C:\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16-HDRI
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
img.dyn=${img.root}\\lib



http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I think that the Imagemagick inside the Alfresco-community release has a bug.
Imagemagick version: 7.0.5-2
I installed last version with all flags during installation wizard ( NOT for associate files to ImageMagick )
Config in global properties:

```
img.root=C:\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16-HDRI
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
img.dyn=${img.root}\\lib
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that alfresco-pdf-renderer was not working in linux (only for txt, ftl,html mimetypes). It was working for other mimetypes. Also, it was working in windows for all mime types:
I resolve it on my linux envt by:
Changing the owner of 'alfresco-pdf-renderer' file from ec2-user to root

```
sudo chown root:root alfresco-pdf-renderer
```

Share admin console properties set at http://hostname:8080/alfresco/s/enterprise/admin/admin-transformations:

```
/app/alfresco/alfresco-pdf-renderer
/app/alfresco/alfresco-pdf-renderer/alfresco-pdf-renderer
```

Imagemagick was already enabled and working fine in my case. Also if above solution does not work, you can try out this - https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/how-do-i-integrate-alfresco-pdf-renderer-in-the-community/td-p/218405